# 2sexy editor automatically create <p> tag

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

At the latest version of 2sexy 4.8.4 the editor always creates a `<p>` tag at the editor field. I don't want that. how can i disable this?
thanks

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to configure this, I'm assuming it's an automatic thing with TinyMCE in combination with the browser you are using.

As a workaround, I recommend that your template checks if the string is this standard empty value, and then does something else, a bit like this

`@(Content.Body == "<p></p>" ? "" : Content.Body)`